# webcam no longer detected after updating Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, webcam

For a while, my microphone wasn't working, but my webcam was. Now I have the reverse problem. Evidently, trying solutions which worked for other users isn't going to cut it, since I have already managed to make my Dell Precision M6800 worse by trying random solutions suggested on various threads (it no longer reliably wakes up from suspend, but reboots instead sometimes). Ubuntu 16.04 LTS was rock stable on my machine, but I have had numerous problems with 18.04 LTS since it was first released. My machine finally started working smoothly after about six months of updates and was stable for some time before things started to go wrong again about six months ago. Anyway, I am frustrated and could really use some more professional help to get things working again (if it is not some hardware failure, which I rather doubt). Since I am not that handy with Ubuntu, I would appreciate some context/explanation for whatever commands are suggested so that I may fare better with troubleshooting in the future. To my understanding, it should be a good start to provide the output of `ls -ltrh /dev/video*`:

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

the output of `getfacl /dev/video`:

```
getfacl: /dev/video: No such file or directory
```

the output of `ls -ltrh /dev/video*`:

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`:

```
Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

and, finally, the output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Saturn XT [FirePro M6100] (rev ff)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tobago HDMI Audio [Radeon R7 360 / R9 360 OEM] (rev ff)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
11:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
```

I have no idea what most of these commands are about in any detail, but I tried to look through all applicable threads for relevant diagnostic commands. Please let me know if I omitted anything potentially important.

EDIT: My microphone is detected by Ubuntu but actually isn't working either.

Comment: First of all you should try using Ubuntu 16.04 Live to see if it appears there. It's important to not use a point release (like 16.04.3) but the true "first" 16.04. Currently it can also be a hardware related problem, not just software.

Comment: 1. Please see if there is any file like /usr/include/linux/videodev2.h or linux/videodev.h  2. try install Webcamoid. and see if it detects your webcam.

Comment: I probably won't have time to try Ubuntu 16.04 Live until the weekend, but I can report that I do have the file /usr/include/linux/videodev2.h, but webcamoid just segfaults when I try to launch it at the terminal after installing it as `sudo apt-get install webcamoid`.